# Get link from Web Browser WP8 C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Please tell me, how can I get `URL` from *web browser*.
Thanks

```
private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
    webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("...", UriKind.Absolute);
    webBrowserTask.Show();
    DispatcherTimer newTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    newTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    newTimer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
    newTimer.Start();   
}

void OnTimerTick(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   // HERE I WANT TO GET URL FROM WEB BROWSER 
}
```

Comment: This is not possible. Just curious, why would one need such thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with a `WebBrowserTask`. It is possible with a `WebBrowser` component embeded in your app, where you can handle the `OnNavigating` event and store the actual url with each user interaction.